# Repeated limit epsilon-delta proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$\lim_n\lim_ma_{m,n}=A\iff\forall n,\forall\epsilon,\exists M,\forall m\ge M,|a_{m,n}-a_n|<\epsilon$ and $\forall\delta,\exists N,\forall n\ge N,|a_n-A|<\delta$

Can $M$ and $N$ depend on each other?

Comment: It is $(\forall n ...)$ and $(\forall \delta ...)$. So I would say no.